# How to insert to excel sheet from view type safely in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am going to insert some data from view to excel sheet but columns with the decimal value does not inserted numeric type, it is been inserted as text .How to solve this problem?
[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZMVS.jpg)

```
 using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();


                for (int i = 0; i < Grid.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Data$] " +
                     "([Title],[Name],[DayOfWeek],[Approval State],[Date],[User ID],[Week],[Project Code],[Project Regular Hours],[Project Overtime Hours],[Sick],[Vacation],[Holiday],[Unpaid Leave],[Other],[Timesheet URL])" +
                     "VALUES(@Title,@Name,@DayOfWeek,@ApprovalState,@Date,@UserID,@Week,@ProjectCode,@ProjectRegularHours,@ProjectOvertimeHours,@Sick,@Vacation,@Holiday,@UnpaidLeave,@Other,@TimesheetURL)", cn);



                    List<OleDbParameter> parameters = new List<OleDbParameter>
                    {
                        new OleDbParameter("@Title", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Title").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Name", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Ad_Soyad").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@DayOfWeek", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"DayOfWeeks").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@ApprovalState", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"ApprovalState").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Date",Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Tarix").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@UserID", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"UserID").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Week", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Weeks").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@ProjectCode", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i, "ProjectCode").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@ProjectRegularHours",Convert.ToDecimal(Grid.GetRowCellValue(i, "ProjectRegularHours").ToString(),new CultureInfo("en"))){DbType=DbType.Decimal},
                        new OleDbParameter("@ProjectOvertimeHours", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"ProjectOvertimeHours").ToString()){DbType=DbType.Decimal},
                        new OleDbParameter("@Sick", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Sick").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Vacation", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Vacation").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Holiday", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Holiday").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@UnpaidLeave", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"UnpaidLeave").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@Other", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Other").ToString()),
                        new OleDbParameter("@TimesheetURL", Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"TimesheetURL").ToString())
                    };

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


            }
```

Comment: How do you insert them? Add your code. What do you mean saying insert "safely"?

Comment: It's impossible to help with problems in your code, if you don't post the code. Excel can handle decimals without any problem. Are you sure you are inserting *decimals* though, instead of localized *strings*?

Comment: Post the *code* in the question, not a screenshot of the code. Screenshots can't be compiled

Comment: BTW `ToString()`. The *code* itself is converting decimals to localized strings instead of storing them in Excel. Just *don't* do that. Cast the value to a `decimal` if you need to

Comment: I tried but code too big

Answer (score 0):

The code itsels is converting the values to *localized* strings before inserting them into Excel. That's guaranteed to cause conversion problems. If you run this code in any European country, 24.5 will become `24,5`.

Don't convert the values into strings. If they are returned as objects, cast them to the correct type first. You don't need to rebuild the command object in every iteration either. Just create it once, pass the *correct* OleDbType and change the parameters for each row, eg:

```
var query="INSERT INTO [Data$] " +
                 "([Title],[Name],[DayOfWeek],[Approval State],[Date],[User ID],[Week],[Project Code],[Project Regular Hours],[Project Overtime Hours],[Sick],[Vacation],[Holiday],[Unpaid Leave],[Other],[Timesheet URL])" +
                 "VALUES(@Title,@Name,@DayOfWeek,@ApprovalState,@Date,@UserID,@Week,@ProjectCode,@ProjectRegularHours,@ProjectOvertimeHours,@Sick,@Vacation,@Holiday,@UnpaidLeave,@Other,@TimesheetURL)";
var cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);

cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Title",OleDbType.VarWChar,20 );
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Name",OleDbType.VarWChar,20 );
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DayOfWeek",OleDbType.VarWChar,20 );
...      

cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ProjectRegularHours",OleDbType.Decimal,19,4);

for (int i = 0; i < Grid.RowCount; i++)
{
    cmd1.Parameters["@Title"].Value = Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"Title");
    ...
    cmd1.Parameters["@ProjectRegularHours"].Value = (decimal)Grid.GetRowCellValue(i,"ProjectRegularHours"))
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

There are better options as well. If your grid uses data binding to bind to a DataTable, you can use an OleDbTableAdapter to write the entire table at once.

An even better option is to use a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) to write any DataTable or collection into a sheet with a single line, with headers and styling, eg:

```
var range=sheet.LoadFromDataTable(myTable,true, TableStyles.Dark1);
```

or

```
var range=sheet.LoadFromCollection(myListOfCustomers);
```

You can also convert the resulting range into a named table :

```
using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(somePath))
{
    // add a sheet
    var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    var table = ws.Tables.Add(range, "table1");
    table.ShowTotal = true;
    table.TableStyle = TableStyles.Light2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks every one for your replay.But this codes do not work for me